# Intent in condition doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have tried searching for this topic but i didn't find anything that would help me, so here I am asking this.

I am a beginner so I don't understand a lot of terms and if you answer my question please try to use simple language so I could understand.

I have a condition in that the elements at same position of two lists are compared and if they aren't equal than it jumps to another activity:

```
if (randomColors.get(i) != userColors.get(i)) {
    Intent i = new Intent( GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and it displays an error in debugging that I cannot solve:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gabie212.simonsays/com.gabie212.simonsays.GameOverActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Please help me, I am a beginner and I don't know what's wrong with my code because I have done exactly as they taught us in class...

Here is the complete code
I know its not the best but its a work in proggress

```
    package com.gabie212.simonsays;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

private int i = 0;
private Thread t = new Thread();
private Button greenButton;
private Button redButton;
private Button blueButton;
private Button yellowButton;
private Button startButton;

private ArrayList<Integer> randomColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> userColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private GameManger gm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gm =  new GameManger(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
    redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
    blueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
    yellowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    greenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    redButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    blueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    yellowButton.setOnClickListener(this);





}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int num;

    num= gm.getColor(4);
    randomColors.add(num);


    android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    //TODO if the start button is pressed multiple times simultaneously it starts the lightup loop multiple times simultaneously
    if (v.getId() == startButton.getId()) {
        for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) //light up loop
        {
            switch (randomColors.get(i)) {
                case 1:
                    greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenlightup);

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                        }
                    }, 2000);


                    break;
                case 2:
                    redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redlightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                        }
                    }, 2000);


                    break;
                case 3:
                    blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluelightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                        }
                    }, 2000);


                    break;
                case 4:
                    yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowlightup);
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                        }
                    }, 2000);


                    break;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() {
                }

            }, 2000);
        }

        for(i=0;i<randomColors.size();i++)
        {

            if(v.getId()==greenButton.getId())
            {
                userColors.add(1);
            }
            else
            {
                if(v.getId()==redButton.getId()){
                    userColors.add(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(v.getId()==blueButton.getId())
                    {
                        userColors.add(3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userColors.add(4);
                    }
                }


            }


        }
        for(i=0;i<randomColors.size();i++)
        {
            if(randomColors.get(i)!=userColors.get(i))
            {

                Intent i = new Intent( GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }



    }

}
}
```

by the its not a simple null pointer exception, at least i don't think so because there is nothing here to be null, there is only a simple intent in an if statement

here's the code for the game over activity

```
    package com.gabie212.simonsays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;



    public class GameOverActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    private Button againButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);
        againButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        againButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent in = new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You make sure Declare class in manifest?

Comment: share the complete code for `GameActivity `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: paste code your button click funtion

Comment: You're calling `setOnClickListener` on a view that doesn't exist. Can you post your code surrounding any `setOnClickListener` instances in `GameOverActivity`?

Comment: can you add more code .. the error happens while executing OnClickListener() ..

Comment: post the code of your `GameOverActivity`

Comment: Paste your complete code of `GameActivity` and `GamOverActivity`

Comment: [Try debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html). Set a breakpoint in `onCreate` in `GameOverActivity` and step through the lines one by one. If any of your buttons are `null` after their line is called, then that's your problem.

Comment: thanks , you just fixed my problem, turns out  i have copied the code to define a button and i didn't changed it so i defined btnAgain as btnStart , thank you very much and sorry for the hassle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `GameOverActivity`, on this line:

```
againButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
```

Your `againButton` is `null` as you are referencing `btnStart` from your main activity layout (`activity_game.xml`). This can't be found because your `GameOverActivity` is using `activity_game_over.xml` for its layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);
```

Any views need to be defined within the `activity_game_over.xml` file for them to be used by the activity. You need to reference the ID of the button as defined in `layout/activity_game_over.xml`

```
againButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgain); // Or whatver you've named it
```

As for your specific question as to why the `Intent` is not working, the `Intent` itself is working fine, it's just that `GameOverActivity` cannot start up properly due to the above issue, and therefore your app crashes.

Comment: thanks again , by defining againButton as btnAgain instead of btnStart i have solved my problem